# Are join-tables from a ManyToMany association available for querying?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony

I am trying to create a query in my Invoice repository to return all <kbd>Invoice</kbd>s that don't have any <kbd>Payment</kbd>s associated to it.

The two entities have a ManyToMany association between them (note the `invoice_payment` join table) as in the following extracts of their entity definitions:

**Class Invoice:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Payment", inversedBy="invoice_ids")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(   name="invoice_payment",
 *            joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoice_ids", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="payment_ids", referencedColumnName="id")} )
 */
protected $payment_ids;
```

**Class Payment:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Invoice", mappedBy="payment_ids")
     */
    protected $invoice_ids;
```

I'm conscious that if I can access the join table `invoice_payment` it should be a very simple lookup - however I haven't found anything in Symfony/Doctrine that discusses accessing non-entity database tables. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is about creating a query yourself (something with NativeQueryBuilder). Also possible with simple Doctrine QueryBuilder or DQL using joins but personnaly, whenever I have joins I avoid them by opting for native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->leftJoin('i.payments_ids', 'p')
   ->andWhere('p is null');
```

on a sidenote, your field names are misleading. payments_ids should be called payments - and same for invoice_ids as inoices. 
They dont return an id, they return a collection of objects.

Comment: Hey @Rufinus, thanks - I just tried it but unfortunately got returned `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'p is null': Error: Cannot add having condition on a non result variables (I queried for a user that has 2 records in invoices and one associated record in payment (and the join table))

Comment: try adding `->select('i', 'p')`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it was not possible with Doctrine, but what you CAN do is to use plain mysql to access the desired table.

Something like:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->somefunctiontogetpuremysql()->query(SELECT * FROM "invoice_payment")
```

Sorry, I don't remember what was that function, you'll have to find it yourself. This method is a bit annoying to work with, because you do not get entities back, you get simple data.

You could also just separate that ManyToMany into ManyToOne and OneToMany on two tables and make that into an actual entity.